# How to delete partitions?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, sql-server-2019

I run the query

```
SELECT so.name, p.* 
FROM sys.partitions p 
INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects so ON p.object_id = so.id 
WHERE partition_number > 1 
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

and I get the 170 rows as result, like

```
ifts_comp_fragment_1336391830_19755845 ....
```

As I understand that are FTS internal partitions.

How can I delete all of FTS partitions?

Comment: Why do you want to delete the internal partitions managed by full-text search? This seems an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I need to get list of unused, missed indexes in db. So I use sp_BlitzIndex (from Brent Ozar) but it writes me: "the db Skipped because Over 100 partitions found ". As I understand these partitions should not change the result but the SP does not work.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `sp_BlitzIndex`? The severity level of this message should be zero in the current version per [this issue](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/1914) and not skip the database.

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded yesterday it.

Comment: I suggest you submit an issue on the project website, including details of the log. You could also ask a new question here to see of someone has a work-around or change the code yourself.

Comment: Hi Dan, could you help: does exist any script to receive list of missing indexes with query to create the index, unused, duplicated indexes? Because sp_BlitzIndex works strange